# How to find an equivalent LC circuit from a combination LC circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, thevenin, kirchhoffs-laws, lcr, resonator

I have a circuit containing a number of L and C, both in parallel and series.
How can I find the equivalent LC circuit (with a single L and C) for such a circuit?
Kirchhoff or Thevenin can give me the equivalent Z, but then I cannot obtain L and C from this.
The aim is to convert the below-shown circuit into a parallel LC resonator. Thanks.

[image: combination circuit for an equivalent LC circuit is to be obtained.]

Comment: Have you tried to actually determine that "equivalent Z" to see if it's possible to make it with a single LC? Hint: you should get a 3rd order in the denominator, and 4th in the numerator.

Answer (score 1):

There is no *exact* equivalent of an arbitrary circuit. It is often possible to find an approximate cirucit in a small frequency range around some point.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you have not decided on the type of connection: do you want L and C to be in series or in parallel. Another problem is that you have 2 variables, but only 1 number. Once you set the connection and find the impedance, you should set an arbitrary value to L or C to find the other value.